# How well do animated GIFs work on the Asus Eee Pad Transformer?

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, images, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I'm looking at buying the Asus Eee Pad Transformer. Before I do, though, I want to see how my Tumblr experience will be on it. What I'm specifically worried about is animated GIFs. When I browse Tumblr on say my iPod Touch or Droid, sometimes GIFs work, sometimes they just don't. I played around with an iPad 1 a while ago and it also had trouble playing some GIFs.

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with the Eee Pad and if it has these same problems with playing animated GIFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't wait and went out and bought one. Turns out GIFs work relatively well. All of them animate. However, too heavy a page can really bog down performance. Tumblr, for instance, only works well if I turn off unlimited scrolling. With only one or two GIFs on the page, they animate well. With a large page, GIFs will animate, but slowly while skipping some frames.

All in all, it's a usable experience.